# how to generate entire response code from http request in java?

Tags: java

I have a code but it is printing only the status, what i want is my code to prnt the entire code "Response" on console.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class API{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://testpath");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work..

```
String statusCode = http.getResponseMessage();
System.out.println(statusCode);
```

Comment: And what if i want to view source of this Response ?

Answer (score 1):

Your class is named API yet you seem to not have carefully read the API for HttpURLConnection. :[

[getResponseMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#responseMessage) is probably what you want.

If you want access to certain headers you will need to use the properties defined in [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

```
The following methods are used to access the header fields and the contents after the connection is made to the remote object:

getContent
getHeaderField
getInputStream
getOutputStream

Certain header fields are accessed frequently. The methods:

getContentEncoding
getContentLength
getContentType
getDate
getExpiration
getLastModifed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getResponseMessage() method from HttpURLConnection  to get completer response message