# I want to view "source code" of the response generated from HTTP request in Java

Tags: java

My code can only return response status message or status code, but I need my code to return response in "view source" format i.e. in XML format :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class API{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        String statusCode = http.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(statusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be genuine question ? Why negative voting ?

Comment: Maybe because you could get answer by typing in google "HttpURLConnection example".

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate entire response code from http request in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946612/how-to-generate-entire-response-code-from-http-request-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get stream and then read it. Like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class API{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");

        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        String statusCode = http.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(statusCode);

          //read the result from the server
          BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
          {
              sb.append(line);
          }

          System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this code, but it gives error in line "sb.append(line + '\n');" says operator + is undefined.

Comment: Try now but it does not matter, you could throw it away `"+'\n'"`